# Fontsize caption tufte class not the same anymore \usepackage{sub fig} causing the problem

Tags: tufte

Normally the font of the marginnote and the caption are the same, but after compiling my document today (and I didn't change anything in the preamble) the font-size is the same size of the font in the text, same with the space between the lines.
The margin notes didn't change.
Is anyone having the same problem?
I know my question is not well documented, but this is really a great problem for me. Making the book in stages, compiling the document now again, makes a total mess of all the previous pages, because some pages are changing qua lay-out.

So my question is, how to make to make to caption of a figure having the same font style  like the the margin note.

Looking further and eliminating things, deleting things in the preamble I've found out dat \usepackage{subfig} was giving the problem. After commenting that line, everything went fine. Except that compiling gives an error \l@subfigure undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the caption package is incompatible to the tufte document class (and vice versa) the subfig package should be loaded without caption package, i.e.

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

Comment: That really save my week!